# Handle page boundaries in flash

Tags: computer-hardware

I am using GD25WD80C for storing the data from a sensor, that sensor data I have read to my MCU (nrf sdk) using TWI. I need 15000 samples read from the sensor to store to GD25WD80C, the page size is 256 bytes. samples from the sensor are available every 0.5 msec. when the sample is ready I want to make the app_timer interrupt . When the app_timer interrupt occur I want to write SDP32 sample value to the flash. when one page is over I want to write to next page. Total 15000 samples should be collected from SDP32 through TWI and wrote into the GD25WD80C using SPI. These two operations should happen paralally. How can I acheive this? I am writing the code in segger embedded studio.

Comment: That sounds like a question for the [Segger Embedded Studio](https://forum.segger.com/) (note capitals) forum.